# Xamarin Forms Dynamic bind image in a ViewCell

Tags: c#, android, data-binding, xamarin.forms

I'm in trouble with dynamic bind of images in a ViewCell. I have a shared project for Android and iOS. My ViewCell is so defined

```
<ViewCell>
    <StackLayout Padding="5" Orientation="Vertical">
        <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal">
            <Image WidthRequest="32" HeightRequest="32" Source="{Binding Image}"></Image>
     <Label Text="{Binding Source}" FontSize="Medium" TextColor="#003056"></Label>
     </StackLayout>
...
```

The Image property is so defined in the class

```
public ImageSource Image {
            get
            {
                ImageSource imageSource = ImageSource.FromResource("MyProject.Images.image001.png");
                return imageSource;
            }
```

The Images folder is in the shared project.
The imageSource returned is not null, there are no errors but the images is not shown.
Can you help, plese?

Thanks

Comment: I just tried your codes with images as `embedded Resource` in PCL. everythings' worked fine, From the problem you mentioned in the comment. I think you should try some other pictures.

Comment: Thank you. I tried with other images but it doesn't work. I find very difficult to control the ViewCell apparence. The height of the row remain the same indipendently of the information I put in.

Comment: Could you share a basic demo that can reproduce the problem? I'll see if I can figure out the problem.

Comment: I found this very helpful - a simple example of a ViewCell loading an image from resources. Bravo !

Answer (score 0):

Ensure each image has Build option set to Embedded Resource using Properties menu(right click) as described here: https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/user-interface/images/

Comment: Yes, they are :-(
The images are in the shared project (not in the Android project). Thx

Comment: Update: int the log I can see
ImageLoaderSourceHandler: Image data was invalid: Xamarin.Forms.StreamImageSource

Comment: Humm, is your image a real png? I've seen some problems with jpeg images named with .png

Comment: Thank you for your suggest.. The problem isn't gone. It's better to abandon Xamari Forms and go to native. Too many problems with ListView.
Thank you

Comment: I totally disagree but that's your choice.

Comment: Why you say so? Can you help me to understand? It's more days that I'm fighting with listview because the item doesn't resize....

Comment: I solved the problem. The image format is ok. But I ha compiled the image as AndroidResource and I put them in the Resources/drawable fodler. To get the image I changed the ProvideValue method to  
`var imageSource = Device.RuntimePlatform == Device.Android ? ImageSource.FromFile(Source) : ImageSource.FromFile("Images/" + Source);`

Comment: `<Image WidthRequest="24" HeightRequest="24" Source="{local:ImageResource  {Binding ImageName} }"></Image>`
Please, what is wrong? Thanks

Comment: Your syntax is incorrect. You cannot use a Binding inside a Custom MarkupExtension (ImageResourceExtension). Use a converter instead: Source="{Binding ImageName, Converter={StaticResource EmbeddedImageToImageSourceConverter}}" and create the appropriate EmbeddedImageToImageSourceConverter (not difficult at all...). But, if you're really looking for performances, I suggest to not use EmbeddedResources but native images. (Cache gestion, optimization, different images by resolution). Ps: If it's not enough for you, you should create a new SO thread with your actual problem.